# Ethernet PHY and their corresponding hardware are represented Right to Left in most datasheets and application notes schematic. Why?

Tags: phy, schematic, drawing, lan

### What's the matter?

If you are here for complicated applied physics, you'll be quite disappointed. This post is just about a bit of electronic world trivia.
I am currently designing a board with two LAN connections and PoE. I am gathering a lot of documentation while drawing the schematic.
Something is looking surprising to me. It looks like most of the combo PHY<->Connectors are represented from Right to Left in the literature, in a way that is inverted from what we would usually expect.

##### What I expect:

- INPUT->OUTPUT
- POWER->CONSUMER
- HOST->DEVICE

##### What I find most of the time for Ethernet:

- PHY->RJ45

The magnetics also, are always shown on the left of the port, and their pin order, packaging, and the way they are drawn implies that the port is going to be on their right following the PHY->RJ45 convention.

### Here are some examples:

[image]
[Microchip AN2157, p12](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/application-notes/an2157)

[image]
[Microchip LAN8840 datasheet, p7](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/UNG/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/LAN8840-Data-Sheet-00004727A.pdf)

[image]
[JASN G24C025P datasheet, p1](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2303150930_JASN-G24C02SP_C5368818.pdf)

[image]
[TI DP83561 datasheet, p1](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/dp83561-sp.pdf)

#### Counter example From TI [Application Report slvaf59, p3](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slvaf59/slvaf59.pdf)

In this example, the LAN port is on the left and power is taped from the left of the transformer. It is a more conventional way of drawing as the input is on the left.

**Notice the mirrored pin order on the LAN Tranformers... Lol**

[image]

### Why is this surprising?

For a USB to UART board for example, most of the schematic will show the USB port on the Left of the schematic. Power inputs are also represented on the left most of the time. It is a well known standard to make the schematic signal or power flow from left to right.

[image]
[Holtek HT42B534-x datasheet, p2](https://www.holtek.com/webapi/116711/HT42B534-xv120.pdf)

[image]
[Silicon Labs CP2102N datasheet, p1](https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/data-sheets/cp2102n-datasheet.pdf)

### Is this important? No, but, curiosity !

It's nothing important really. But Instinctively, you might have believed that the Left to Right standard way of drawing things apply to most if not all kind of electronic circuits. I just showed that it is not really the case for LAN. I don't understand why a HOST->PORT convention took the upper hand in this case, and against the established left to right standard of the other type of ports. And it is getting me quite curious.

Comment: Ethernet, USB, RS485, CAN et cetera all have signals in both directions.

Comment: @RussellH still doesn't explain why it seems that the LAN standard is inverted compared to other ports. USB is bidirectional too, yet it is represented left to right PORT->Host

Comment: Alright. Found the answer. I am mostly looking at switch related datasheets and app notes, but my application is for a powered device. So, I am intuitively thinking 'receptor and input' for my project, but the documentation is telling 'source and output'.

Comment: One Important thing I keep from this is that LAN transformer datasheets seem to be drawn in a 'source' or 'output' perspective for which the PHY is logically on the left in the schematic. It is something to clearly keep in mind when designing a board. The choke have quite an influence on the data integrity and it is then quite easy to mess up that part. 
The TI screenshot is a bad example, but you can notice the inverted (x mirrored) pin order on the magnetics. 
Will edit the question to reflect those findings.

Comment: Getting back to what I've said. Even for single port PHYs and MACs, it is still represented Right to Left. Weird. Just wanna know why and if it is a convention.

Comment: Please bear in mind that it's a Q&A site, not a discussion forum with lots of exchanges in comments. Thanks.

Comment: @Tioneb What is the question really? And the logical order is highly subjective, but usually drawn from left to right, MCU, PHY, magnetics (unless intrgrated to connector) and connector, because it is the expected flow how you make an Ethernet interface to MCU, even if the PHY gives clocks to MCU or the device is using PoE instead of sourcing. Nothing prevents you from using any other comvention, such as putting outside world connections to left and MCU connections to right on a PHY. The MCU is still the "host" to the PHY "device", as you already expected for hosts and devices.

Comment: @Justme this is the best answer so far. The MCU is host to the PHY in all configuration. It's not the case for USB->UART because the upstream USB device is configuring the interface. Would mark as best answer if it was an answer.

Comment: @Tioneb For the USB to UART chips, the chips themselves are USB devices. So if you are looking at the chip itself, or a standalone product that is an USB to UART adapter, USB would be on left as expected. Now, if you are making an MCU board which needs USB UART IC for connectivity, the MCU will be the "host" that simply needs to communicate with the PC, so in that sense, MCU will be on the left, and any PHY interface chip on right (Ethernet, USB UART, RS232 PHY, RS485 PHY or CAN PHY) will be on right, and finally the appropriate interface connector on right of PHY IC.

Comment: Tione - You mentioned that the comment from @Justme was actually a suitable answer and this was flagged to us by another site member. || While we cannot force users to write an answer as an actual *answer*, [answers should not be written in comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work), no matter how well-intentioned the comments are intended to be. Therefore, I have used a process to copy that comment from Justme (and its follow-up) into an actual answer (with attribution to the original source).

Answer (score 1):

Western preference for text flow is left-to-right.

Electronics being primarily a Western invention means that this left-to-right bias carries over in many types of diagrams, including schematics. Left-to-right signal flow is even enforced style in some organizations.

That said, things get weird when considering bidirectional ports, like Ethernet or USB. Being bidirectional, placing the port on left or right is equally valid, at least based on signal flow.

How do deal with this? A popular way to think about it is the *control relationship*. So we have the Ethernet Controller -> Port, which would tend to place the RJ45 on the right.

But what if for example you're describing a switch? There, your backbone port would face left, and hub clients to the right, since that is how control tends to flow.

Likewise for USB there is an upstream-facing vs. downstream-facing notion, which would tend to place the former on the left and the latter on the right.

Comment: Yes, it's one of the quirks of the representation. You instinctively represented hierarchical flow from left to right (as in HOST->DEVICE). So, it makes sense for a LAN Switch to have its ports on the right and the MCU on the left. 
For USB Hubs, diagrams show the upstream on top and downstream on the bottom, which makes sense. For LAN, it seem that everything is stuck on a 'HOST' perspective and this is what feels arbitrary and somewhat counterintuitive to me.

Answer (score 0):

Usually in 70-80 percent of documentation/schematics, analog systems put inputs on the left and outputs on the right. It's an artifact of reading from left to right, and most people follow the same way in a diagram.

It happens in multiple places:

- In [biology schematics](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjy0ajjtvaDAxW4OkQIHakGAn8QFnoECCIQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.researchgate.net%2Ffigure%2FSchematic-representation-of-the-inputs-left-and-outputs-right-of-the-main-families-of_fig4_370802415&usg=AOvVaw1-PtBo2gCmvC6zyDELk5cq&opi=89978449)
- In [audio inputs](https://www.reddit.com/r/synthesizers/comments/b484il/why_do_guitar_pedals_tend_to_have_input_jack_on/)
- In [schematic rules for some people](https://www.protoexpress.com/kb/schematic-design-rules/)

While there are mostly no guidelines for this behavior it is a natural thing to do for most people who read from left to right.

The LAN ports are on the right side because they are considered to be inputs. The digital out to the rest of the design and thus flows from left to right.

The problem is in many designs, what is considered and output and input, because designers generally place inputs on the left and outputs on the right. Many people don't reach the same consensus on what is an input and what is an output, hence some variation.

Comment: Hey thanks, ofc this is well known. My question is about LAN ports being on the right side of schematics, not left like other ports.

Comment: And why it seems to be a convention.

Comment: Sorry, thought that was apparent, added

Comment: Also, there is the LAN switch versus LAN device perspective which seem to influence the positions of the port on the schematic. I'm starting to understand where my confusion comes from and commented a bit more under the post. The LAN magnetics are often represented from a switch perspective. Will try to synthesis tomorrow.

Comment: It's more a question of Host->Device here I guess. I bet if I pull a USB hub schematic, the USB ports will be on the right.

Answer (score 0):

Ethernet is bidirectional, just like, say, a serial port, so there's no clear notion of "input" and "output" *unless* there's a clear host-device or consumer-producer relationship in the design of the system.

Let's think of what options are there:

- PHY↔MAG↔RJ45
- RJ45↔MAG↔PHY

They are both equally "good" or "bad". It's not like the data flows one way only.

> For a USB to UART board for example, most of the schematic will show the USB port on the Left of the schematic.

It's a bidirectional connection again. We got three options:

1. To a USB device that mostly produces data (say a camera), the upstream-facing connection would be functionally an "output", so it would belong on the right, say.
2. To a USB device that mostly consumes data (say a display), the upstream-facing connection would be functionally an "input", so it would belong on the left.
3. To a USB device that functionally is both a source and a destination (say a storage device), the upstream-facing connection is functionally "input/output". I guess it belongs on the top of the page then? :)

So, neither the "PHY convention" nor "USB convention" is *the* right way to do it. It depends on the application. Moreover, commercial products are often done under a lot of time-to-market pressure and the art of making schematics is virtually lost. Typical "complex system" app notes from major vendors have schematics that look rubbish, so I wouldn't be learning anything from those other than what not to do.

Personally, I use the "3/4-point-compass" convention I mentioned above with the USB example. It works reasonably well for USB, Ethernet, Serial, etc. The side of the page the connector is on indicates the primary data flow:

- mostly consumer = input = on the left,
- mostly producer = output = on the right,
- uncommitted bidirectional on the device, or without host-device distinction = on the top,
- uncommitted bidirectional on the host side = on the bottom

---

These days, schematics seem to be drawn in offices where there's just one paper size - A4 or Letter, so the nice large A3/11x17 or even larger schematics of the past seem to be gone. I'm on board with the GIS folks - big formats rock. Even if someone doesn't have a DesignJet or similar printer in the office, print shops are virtually everywhere. A complex SoC-based system can fit nicely on a single A2 sheet. I believe that the visual continuity has big benefits when reading such a schematic. Having it cut up into a few dozen A4 pages, with lots of space taken up by boilerplate and title blocks, is downright silly to me. Oh well...

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways, I suppose.

1. PHY left, media right

   This seems more conventional, but half the signal path is right-to-left.  *It is a bidirectional communications medium* after all, and we're merely making an arbitrary pick.  That said, this may be more common when the port is used as an output, or client (initiates communications).
2. PHY right, media left

   This may be more common where the port is used as an input, or server.
3. Strict input on left, output on right

   This would be most logical for signal flow, with the problem that you'd have to split the IC symbol into multiple parts to be consistent, maybe the connector too, or maybe you'd be lazy and use net labels to do this and -- it's a stinking disorganized mess, don't. :)

Answer (score 0):

The OP, [Tioneb](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/207455/tioneb), reports that the first comment below from [Justme](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/199993/justme) was a suitable answer, as follows:

[Comment](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/698761/ethernet-phy-and-their-corresponding-hardware-are-represented-right-to-left-in-m#comment1860850_698761) by [Justme](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/199993/justme):

> @Tioneb What is the question really? And the logical order is highly subjective, but usually drawn from left to right, MCU, PHY, magnetics (unless intrgrated to connector) and connector, because it is the expected flow how you make an Ethernet interface to MCU, even if the PHY gives clocks to MCU or the device is using PoE instead of sourcing. Nothing prevents you from using any other comvention, such as putting outside world connections to left and MCU connections to right on a PHY. The MCU is still the "host" to the PHY "device", as you already expected for hosts and devices.

Follow-up [comment](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/698761/ethernet-phy-and-their-corresponding-hardware-are-represented-right-to-left-in-m#comment1860990_698761) by [Justme](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/199993/justme):

> @Tioneb For the USB to UART chips, the chips themselves are USB devices. So if you are looking at the chip itself, or a standalone product that is an USB to UART adapter, USB would be on left as expected. Now, if you are making an MCU board which needs USB UART IC for connectivity, the MCU will be the "host" that simply needs to communicate with the PC, so in that sense, MCU will be on the left, and any PHY interface chip on right (Ethernet, USB UART, RS232 PHY, RS485 PHY or CAN PHY) will be on right, and finally the appropriate interface connector on right of PHY IC.

---

<sub>(An answer was written as a comment, instead of an answer. Therefore the comment has been copied into this actual answer and I have applied the approach explained [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/252303) to post someone else's content as an answer, with appropriate attribution, in accordance with the [CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) license. The answer has also been set to "Community wiki" so that I don't earn any points from upvotes on this answer, as it isn't *my* answer. However the answer can still receive votes to show its usefulness, as usual.)</sub>